# Error when replace alt in image tag?

Tags: php

I have a test code using simple_dom_html:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$content = '<img src="name1.jpg" alt="name"><img src="name2.jpg" alt="name2">';
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($content);
$array_alt = array();
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    $element->src = "new src";
    $array_alt[] = $element->alt;
}
for($i=0; $i<count($array_alt); $i++) {
    $array_alt[$i] = "test" . $i;
}
echo $html;
```

OUTPUT:

```
$html= '<img src="new src" **alt="name"**><img src="newsrc" **alt="name2"**>';
```

Error when echo $content, alt not change from name "name1", "name2" to "test1", "test2", how to fix it ?

Comment: @xdazz, there is no error. I think, that the output is different then suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change yours two loops to:

```
//....
$i=0;
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    $element->src = "new src";
    $element->alt = "test" . $i;
    $i++;
}
//....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$content = '<img src="name1.jpg" alt="name"><img src="name2.jpg" alt="name2">';
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($content);

$i=0;
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    $element->src = "new src";
    $element->alt = "test".$i;
    $i += 1;
}

echo $html;

?>
```